# How to declare schematype/datatype of a field in mongoose which is the objetid of an item in another collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a bit confused by something in MongoDB, when using Mongoose, since I am new to it. I have two collections: authors and posts.

each author in the authors collection have the mongodb inbuilt id associated with them, which as per my understanding is of the schematype/datatype `Objectid`.

Now in my posts collection,  I have a field which has is called `author`, which should have the value of the author's `Objectid`, similar to the foreign key concept in SQL.

My question is, which schematype/datatype should I declare the author field in the posts collection? Should I put it as `Objectid`? If so, would it not auto-increment and not be settable?

Mockup Of Schemas:

```
var authors = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
email: String
});

var posts = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
author: **??**
});
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for that:

```
var authors = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String
});

var posts = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' }
  // assuming the model will be called 'Author'
});
```

To use:

```
// Get 'author' some how (create a new one, query the
// database for existing authors, etc);
...

// Create a new post and associate it with 'author' by referencing its `_id`:
var post = new Post({
  ...
  author : author._id
});
post.save(...);
```

The documentation linked above also shows how you can get Mongoose to automatically retrieve the `author` document when you're querying posts.